# Filtering rows using ISO8601 timestamps string in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am attempting to filter records upto a certain point using the following SQL

```
select
 orders.total_due,
 orders.created_at
from orders
where orders.last_modified > '2018-03-29T17:44:15.371070+00:00'
order by orders.id;
```

Note that my operator is a plain greater than. So I expect records more recent than the timestamp above. However, the returned results are strange:

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]-----------------------------
total_due  | 100.0
created_at | 2018-03-29 17:44:15.371069+00
```

Strange, since this record can only be matched by an equality or less than operator (the record returned is at the same as the one used by the filter).

Changing the filter timestamp reveals something more interesting. Incrementing the filtering timestamps into a future date time (by upto ~ 5 minutes) still allows the record to be returned.

```
 --  20 seconds after record
 #  select
     orders.total_due,
     orders.created_at
    from orders
    where orders.last_modified > '2018-03-29T17:44:35.371070+00:00'
    order by orders.id;
-[ RECORD 1 ]-----------------------------
total_due  | 100.0
created_at | 2018-03-29 17:44:15.371069+00

 --  300 seconds after record
 #  select
     orders.total_due,
     orders.created_at
    from orders
    where orders.last_modified > '2018-03-29T17:49:35.371070+00:00'
    order by orders.id;
-[ RECORD 1 ]-----------------------------
total_due  | 100.0
created_at | 2018-03-29 17:44:15.371069+00

 --  15 minutes after record
 #  select
     orders.total_due,
     orders.created_at
    from orders
    where orders.last_modified > '2018-03-29T17:59:35.371070+00:00'
    order by orders.id;
(0 rows)
```

DB version: postgres 9.6

```
$ dpkg -l |grep postg |grep 9.6
ii  postgresql                                9.6+181+deb9u1                              all          object-relational SQL database (supported version)
ii  postgresql-9.6                            9.6.6-0+deb9u1                              amd64        object-relational SQL database, version 9.6 server
ii  postgresql-client-9.6                     9.6.6-0+deb9u1                              amd64        front-end programs for PostgreSQL 9.6
ii  postgresql-contrib-9.6                    9.6.6-0+deb9u1                              amd64        additional facilities for PostgreSQL
```

Am I doing something obviously wrong?

Comment: Your query looks at `orders.last_modified` but your output shows `orders.created_at`.

Comment: ah crap. you are right :(